# How to sort search results by "Trending"?

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, node.js, web

In my case, I want to filter search results based on Trending (Based on upvotes versus time only).

Here are some examples of websites that implement a "Trending sort":

http://8tracks.com/explore/all

https://news.ycombinator.com/news

https://www.reddit.com/

The two options I see:

**1. Calculate score on-the-fly (on every page load)**

This is the solution I currently have. Every page load calls a MySQL query and calculates a score for every row in the table. This seems like the most accurate, real-time approach. The problem is the more items to compare, the longer it takes. Right now with around 1.2mil rows, it takes over 3 seconds. In a production scenario, I'm aiming at < 100-300 ms.

**2. Schedule a task to run every X minutes and pre-compute the scores**

This seems like a good solution, but the very obvious problem I see is where do you store the results? Updating every row in the database takes such a long time (I have around 1.2mil rows).

Extensive Googling helped me determine which trending algorithm to use, but not how to implement it in a production scenario.

Here's a simple example of my database:

```
table_topic
id
title


table_upvotes
topic_id
user_id
created_at
```

And here is the actual scoring algorithm (http://amix.dk/blog/post/19574):

```
exports.hackerHot = function (gravity) {
  if (gravity == null) {
    gravity = 1.8;
  }
  return function (votes, itemDate) {
    var hourAge = (Date.now() - itemDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600);
    return (votes - 1) / Math.pow(hourAge + 2, gravity);
  };
};
```

Comment: Trending or Based on upvotes only ? Trending = math, upvotes = sort...

Answer (score 1):

If based on the time, so "Trending" as "Got many upvotes in the last 24 hours" for example, you should get a good performance boost if you calculate the score only for the concerned rows and not the whole database, thus allowing it to be made on-the-fly.

And the only other interpretation I understand is a sort by upvote count, so this shouldn't take too much time either and so it should be possible to do this on-the-fly too.

If you want more elaborated answers, you will have to elaborate on the exact algorithm you chose to implement.

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question to include the actual algorithm used. Your approach might be better. Instead of calculating all the upvotes since the `created_at` date, normalizing the scores and then comparing them, I could  could count the number of upvotes in the last X hours.

Comment: I will have to run tests and compare performance. 

Do you see any possible solution not involving on-the-fly calculations?